# Rails route not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this form:

```
= form_for :vouchers, as: :post, url: '/voucher' do |f|
    = text_field_tag 'code'
    = button_tag I18n.t('activation_code'), class: 'btn', type: 'submit'
```

This route:

`post '/voucher', to: 'webshoppages#webshop_voucher_post'`

And this error: `uninitialized constant WebshoppagesController`

==

When I place the route declaration within a `namespace :webshop_flow do ... end` block, it errors out telling me: `Route [POST] /nl/bestellen/voucher` does not exist.

`rake routes` actually mentions `voucher POST /voucher(.:format)                                     webshoppages#webshop_voucher_post`

Comment: The route is fine, go look at your controllers and see if `WebshoppagesController` exists. Hint: it doesn't. If it does, your second part of the question leads me to believe you've namespaced it.

Comment: have you tried to remove the "/" from the "post '/voucher'" in the routes.rb file?

Comment: Typically class name typo or file name typo

Comment: I do have `app/controllers/webshop_flow/webshoppages_controller.rb` with declaration `class WebshopFlow::WebshoppagesController < ContentpagesController`.

Comment: When removing the `/`, I receive the same error.

Comment: Do the following:
1) `post '/voucher', to: 'webshoppages#webshop_voucher_post', as: voucher` 2) Update your url in form like: `form_for :vouchers, as: :post, url: voucher_path`

Answer (score 0):

I got it. You namespaced your controller. you should use the namespace block in the routes.rb file like that:

```
namespace :webshop_flow, path: '/' do
    post 'voucher', to: webshoppages#action
end
```

in your form, you try:

```
form_for :voucher, webshop_flow_voucher_url do |f|
    # your form here
end
```

Comment: I am now receiving `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`, what is wrong?

Comment: sorry, I forgot the :voucher param. fixed